# Post-build event command line based on project variable

Tags: c#, visual-studio, build, post-build-event, build-events

I need to make a call to a batch file when I finish my project build.

I need to make different calls based on a variable in my c# project. How can I do? This is what I need:

```
AppHelper.cs
public enum CompilingDefines
{
    XNET,
    NOTIFIER
}
public static CompilingDefines CompiledFor { get; set; }
```

Differnt Build-event calls:

NOTIFIER version

```
call "$(TargetDir)CreaPacchettoNotifier.bat"
```

XNET version

```
call "$(TargetDir)CreaPacchettoXNet.bat"
```

Comment: Hi, maybe something like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-use-environment-variables-in-a-build?view=vs-2017)?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming XNET and NOTIFIER are build configurations, you might as well use `$(Configuration)` and `$(Platform)`

Comment: No, they are just constant in my project

Comment: Depending on the variable set do an if check whether the variable is empty or any other logic you might like - https://ss64.com/nt/if.html